Can I use a drawing tablet as a mouse?
My wireless mouse (model MC227, came with wireless keyboard if relevant) just decided to stop working on me, and my only other alternatives are a Gaomon drawing tablet and a wireless mouse that I'm not sure would work and that just don't like. My preferred version is Minecraft: Bedrock, but if this can only work in Minecraft: Java Edition I'd be fine with the switch. I think I'm on Windows 10 but I'm not 100% sure of it.

probably. I have a Huion drawing tablet, and basically all it does is move the mouse around while holding LMB. So probably, yes. Give it a go, I don't see anything negative about trying.

My wacom bamboo has a mousepad mode, maybe check if yours have that. Turn the switch, and it becomes an oversized mousepad. Typically the screen tablets either support pen-only or have a touch screen as well.

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a computer-related question not specific to video games. It is better suited at Super User.

@galacticninja Isn’t the question asking if MC allows a drawing tablet as an input device? If so, it seems on-topic to me (whether the OS accepts a drawing tablet at all though would be off topic).

@Daemons If the OS allows a drawing tablet to function as a mouse, I can't see why Minecraft would not support it.

And at least the OP could try it first :)

It depends on the tablet. Some support touch, while others don't.
If it supports touch (this is different from pen pressure/contact), it is able to detect a finger.
Take for example, the Wacom Intuos/Bamboo series, which has a touchpad switch that allows you to use the tablet as a touchpad.
However, the Wacom Clique/One are screen displays and do not support touchscreen at all; it's pen-input only...
Whereas something like a Samsung Galaxy S22 or iPad with an Apple Pencil aka. a smartphone can be used with a stylus (usually for art) or with your fingers...

Within the brand (Gaomon) you have stated, some models have touch*, some have "nipples"** while others don't support touch***.
You should review each model you wish to buy to check if it supports the functionality you are looking for (other than using the stylus to draw something).
*In my region, there doesn't seem to be any available touch-capable tablets
**"Nipples" are small touch sensitive areas, typically different to the rest of the device or tiny over-sensitive joysticks, usually wedged between a bunch of keys
***You can tell by the slash (/) in the product's specifications.
